# Need Currency symbol inside kendo numerix textbox

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have the below jsfiddle, whereas I am have numerix textbox inside my grid template. Is that possible to prefix with $ symbol inside Textbox.

I tried format:"{0:c2}", that is not working .

```
`format:"{0:c2}"`
http://jsfiddle.net/D4g8S/159/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, don't know why but you cannot use MVVM format in case of templates.

Anyway, you can add some class to your input in template and then you need to change init like this

```
$('.test').kendoNumericTextBox({
    format: "c2"
});
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ouf1kjh4/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your code Ademar. Do you know how to do the same using in angular JS.

We are not using Jquery in our project.

Comment: Well, sorry, in that way I cannot help. I do not know anything about angular.

Answer (score 0):

Here's probably what you're looking for. I've taken the liberty to convert your grid over to MVVM, and make that field editable and use an editor to support currency values.

```js
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    source: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    Name: { type: "string", editable: false },
                    Cost: { type: "number" }
                }
            }
        }
    }),
    costEditor: function(container, options) {
        $("<input data-bind='value: " + options.field + "' name='" + options.field + "' />")
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoNumericTextBox({
                format: "{0:c2}"
            });
    }
});
kendo.bind("body", viewModel);
viewModel.source.add({
    Name: "User 1",
    Cost: 100
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.blueopal.min.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div data-role="grid"
     data-height="365"
     data-bind="source: source"
     data-editable="incell"
     data-scrollable="virtual: true"
     data-columns="[
         { field: 'Name', title: 'Contact Name', width: 200 },
         { field: 'Cost', format: '{0:c2}', editor: viewModel.costEditor }
     ]"></div>
```